# Is it still considered time series if one uses additional signals

Tags: time-series

Apologies in advance, time series is not my strength.

Say I want to predict f(T+1) using f(T-1, T-2, ..., T-N) -- for example using a multi-level preceptron.

If I want to enhance this using some other signals say using weather data on times T-1, T2, ..., T-N

Would this still be considered Time Series Analysis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's still generally considered to be time series.

For example, models of this kind - ones depending on past $x$ and past $y$ - include transfer function models (see, for example, Box and Jenkins (1972) *Time series analysis: Forecasting and control*), and ARIMA models with regressors (also see ARIMAX models). On the second, there are some questions here on CrossValidated, such as:

[Time Series Forecasting with Daily Data: ARIMA with regressor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58657/time-series-forecasting-with-daily-data-arima-with-regressor)

[ARIMA and external regressors in SAS and R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59305/arima-and-external-regressors-in-sas-and-r)